# ¿Se pueden recibir Notificaciones a una URL de las Solicitudes de Dinero?

Tags: mercadopago

Me gustraia saber si mercadopago envia notificaciones de los pagos que pertenecen a una solicitud de dinero 
e configurado una url de mi servicio para recibir notificaciones en https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications
pero no me llegan notificaciones de pagos realizado a una solicitud de dinero creada manualmente desde la pagina de mercadopago

Comment: Bienvenido edita la pregunta y muestra el codigo para enteder mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes información en el apartado de Desarrolladores de MercadoPago. Te dejo el enlace para que lo revises. Saludos
https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/es/guides/notifications/ipn

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque si el enlace de rompe y deja de funcionar, entonces la respuesta deja de tener sentido. Edita la respuesta para añadir un resumen del contenido de la página enlazada (manteniendo el enlace como referencia). Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.